# pushing outdated changes

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Some time ago I forked a repo in bitbucket and committed my changes. Now I want to send a pull request to the original repository. Unfortunately my repo is now out-of-date and there is a conflict. What is the recommended way of pushing changes to the original repository in such cases?

I can pull changes, merge, commit and send pull request but in that case my  pull request contains not only my changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case your pull request should just contain your changes and a merge. Since they already have those changesets that you pulled and merged with, the only changesets they're going to see as incoming are yours and the merge. That probably isn't that much of a problem. Depending on the complexity of the merge and your decisions when manually resolving those conflicts, there is still the chance that they'll look at it and decide not to use it.

The way some do it is to maintain a stack of patches of their changes against a repository. The repository is kept up-to-date and the patches rebased on top of the latest changes so that they're kept up-to-date.

Depending on the size and openness of the project you forked, they may be wary of a bunch of changes if they haven't accepted your work before. In cases like that, it's better to start off submitting smaller sets of changes to break the ice.